# Simulating the find command: why is my code not recursing correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

My assignment is to write a Unix shell script that asks the user for the name of a directory, and then works exactly like `find`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_lister()
{
    cd "$1"
    echo "$1"
    list=$(ls -l ${1})


    nolines=$(echo "$list" | awk 'END{printf "%d",NF}')

    if [ $nolines -eq 2 ]
    then

        echo "$1"

        return
    fi

    filelist=$(echo "$list" | grep ^-.*)
    dirlist=$(echo "$list" | grep ^d.*)

    filename=$(echo "$filelist"| awk '{printf "%s\n",$NF}')
    present=$(pwd)
    echo "$filename"| awk -v pres=$present '{printf "%s/%s\n",pres,$0}'

    dirlist2=$(echo "$dirlist" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$NF}')

    echo "$dirlist2" | while IFS= read -r line;
    do
        nextCall=$(echo "$present/$line");
        dir_lister $nextCall;
        cd ".."
    done
    cd ".."
}



read -p "Enter the name of the direcotry: " dName

dir_lister $dName
```

The problem is, after a depth of three directories, this script gets into an infinite loop, and I don't see why.

EDIT:

Here is the code i came up with after looking at your answer, it still doesn't go more than 1 directory depth:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob # don't miss "hidden files"
shopt -s nullglob # don't fail on empty directories


list_directory()
{
    cd "$2"
    cd "$1"
    ##echo -e "I am called \t $1 \t $2"
    for fileName in "$1/"* 
    do
        ##echo -e "hello \t $fileName"
        if [ -d "$fileName" ];
        then
            echo "$fileName"
            list_directory $fileName $2

        else
            echo "$fileName"
        fi
    done

}
read -p "Enter the direcotory Name: " dirName
var=$(pwd)
list_directory $dirName $var
```

Comment: Why do you need to 'simulate' find instead of just using find? Where is your question?

Comment: @jordanm its part of my homework

Comment: Question doesn't specify what the actual problem is

Comment: Please see the changes i made to my question

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Please help me, I am desperate for this result, been trying it for a day now

Comment: I don't know about the infinite loop, but if you `cd $1` and then `ls $1` you're not getting the list of files you think you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that is completely the wrong way to list files in a directory (see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). I'll give you the pieces and you should be able to put them together into a working script.

Put this at the top of your script:

```
shopt -s dotglob # don't miss "hidden files"
shopt -s nullglob # don't fail on empty directories
```

Then you can easily loop over directory contents with:

```
for file in "$directory/"* ; do
   #...
done
```

Test if you have a directory:

```
if [ -d "$file" ] ; then
   # "$file" is a directory, recurse...
fi
```

Comment: I added the code that i came up with after seeing your answer, but there is still something wrong with it. Can you please tell me what's the problem with my code before they close this question.

Comment: @sasidhar you don't need `cd`